# Finding out which component is pressed

Tags: react-native

How do I know which activity detail has been pressed?

```
renderPeople() {
        if (this.state.teachers != null && this.state.teachers.length >= 1) {
          return this.state.teachers.map(teacher => (
            <ActivityDetail key={teacher.UID} person={teacher} onPress={() => this.setState({ isTeacherVisible: true })} />
          ));
        }
        return null;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save `UID` to props as well,

```
this.setState({ isTeacherVisible: true, selectedTeacher: teacher.UID })
```

full code:

```
renderPeople() {
    if (this.state.teachers != null && this.state.teachers.length >= 1) {
        return this.state.teachers.map(teacher => (
        <ActivityDetail key={teacher.UID} person={teacher} onPress={() => this.setState({ isTeacherVisible: true, selectedTeacher: teacher.UID })} />
        ));
    }
    return null;
}
```